# How to passing an array to the bind_param method as an argument in oop

Tags: php, mysqli

When I want to pass an array to bind_param method, I get an error like the following.

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\libs\Database.php on line 26

Here is code:

```
class Database extends mysqli {

    function __construct($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME) {
        parent::__construct($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
    }

    function insert($table, $data){

        echo $table . '<br />';
        print_r($data);
        echo '<br />';        
        $param_types=$this->gettypes_bind_param($data, $keys, $values, $place_holder);
        $field_names= implode(', ', $keys);
        $inputArray[]=&$param_types;
        $j= count($values);
        for ($i=0;$i<$j;$i++)
        {
            $inputArray[]=&$values[$i];
        }

        print_r($inputArray); 
        echo '<br />';
        $result= $this->prepare("INSERT INTO $table ($field_names) VALUES ($place_holder)");
        call_user_func_array(array($result, 'bind_param'), $inputArray);
        $result->execute();
        die;
    }

    function gettypes_bind_param(&$data, &$keys, &$values, &$place_holder){
        $types='';
        foreach ($data as $tmp)
        {
            switch (gettype($tmp))
            {
                case "string" :
                    $types.='s';
                    break;
                case "integer" :
                    $types.='i';
                    break;                
                case "double" :
                    $types.='d';
                    break;                
                default :
                    $types.='b';
                    break;                
            }
            $place_holder .='?, ';
        }
        $place_holder= rtrim($place_holder, ', ');
        $keys = array_keys($data);
        $values = array_values($data);
        return $types;
    }
```

Sorry, for my English

Comment: `$result->execute($inputArray);` is one option http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php examples here

Comment: Thanks, for your answer but, it's not PDOStatement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Argument unpacking (...)](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) operator...

```
$result->bind_param ($param_types, ...$values);
```

Note that you pass the types and values as separate items and don't have to join them as you would in `call_user_func_array()`.

Comment: Thanks you very very much :)